# Python dataframe subsetting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have two dataframes:-

```
df1=(15651,55)
df2=(12292,1)
```

df1 is a complete dataset. df2 only consists of IDs of customers. The Customer ID column in common in both dataframes. I want to obtain the records of 12292 unique customer ids in df2 from df1.

```
start_algorithm = time.time()
myunique = data_full['CUSTOMER_ID'].unique()
for i in myunique:
#     itemp = customers_data[customers_data['Customer_ids'] == i]
#     data_subset.append(itemp)
      k1 = customers_data.loc[(customers_data['Customer_ids'] == i)]
```

But I am failing to do so. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the myunique ids should based on your df2(customers_data), but not df1 (full_data)

```
myunique = customers_data['CUSTOMER_ID'].unique()
```

Then you can apply a boolean filter to select those from df1 (full) that appear in myunique:

```
new_df=data_full[data_full['Customer_ids'].isin(myunique)]
```

Notice that 'CUSTOMER_ID' and 'Customer_ids' are not identical column names, becuase python is case-sensitive. Here I only assume that you have 'CUSTOMER_ID' in customers_data, and 'Customer_ids' in data_full.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like a `merge`:

```
df_ = data_full.merge(customers_data, how='left',
                      left_on='CUSTOMER_ID',right_on='Customer_ids')
```

assuming `data_full` is what you called `df2` in your question

Answer (score 0):

Are the customer IDs in df1 unique? In that case, you should index df1 by CUSTOMER_ID:

```
df1_indexed = df1.set_index('CUSTOMER_ID')
```

To then call a specific subset of customer IDs becomes really easy (and fast):

```
df1_indexed_subset = df1_indexed.loc[myunique, :]
```

where "myunique" is as you defined it in your question.